# Extract some columns from csv file into excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a csv file contain a lot of columns, I want to extract  6 clomuns (A,B,E,C,K,N and P) from it to an excel sheet file using VBA
It’s my first time using vba so I have looked into the internet  what I found is a code that open an excel file (not a csv ) read the 6 clomuns  and save it into excel file then close it ,but it doesn't work with csv file is there any modification to make this code work on csv file

This my current csv file extracted from a tool,

This is the content of the file ,every line is between {}

```
id;Origine;Mail;Ref;NumD;Domain;FM;MC;ForUser;Subject;CreDate;senderCell;sender;RecDate;WorkDone;enDest
{1002;;YES;DDE/785JJ596/M;QQ-85600023784563-PP8500TT;Repair;Repair and solde;Reload again;The item is defective the user should reclaim .It will be reported to the right person ;reclaim for repair;03/03/2017 10:51;New Orleans ;Jack LeGrand;2017-02-12 14:20:44.0;;;Chicago}
{10083;10069;No;MTM/85KK230Y/A;AZ-785HH01784563-PP8500TT;Vendor;Solde;New item;a new item will be solde as second use;Sole the Item;01/04/2017 17:15;washington;Bruce Liam;2017-03-12 15:35:40.0;Gais Said;Nivada}
{203569;;YES;QQA/8569PP00/P;SD-44UJ986XX1000-WW001258;ABORT;ABORT for non use;Item defected;Item defective problem explicit,Reuse is not an option;User reject the Item please give your opinion;01/02/2017 10:15;mississippi;David  Los;2017-01-22 19:35:40.0;Berlingo fraudi;mississippi}
```

**Update:
this code work for csv and this is the *result* of it file now but it copy all fields and the data given per line how can I format them by colmuns this how they look**

[image]

```
  Sub rangecopy()

Dim myCSVFile As Workbook, wantedFilexls As Workbook

'ouvrir le classeur source (en lecture seule)
Set  myCSVFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\CSV\myCSVFile.csv")
'définir le classeur destination
Set wantedFilexls = ThisWorkbook
myCSVFile.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A:B").Copy wantedFilexls.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A:B")
myCSVFile.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("E:E").Copy wantedFilexls.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("C:C")
myCSVFile.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("K:K").Copy wantedFilexls.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("D:D")
myCSVFile.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("N:N").Copy wantedFilexls.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("E:E")
myCSVFile.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("P:P").Copy wantedFilexls.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("F:F")

'fermer le classeur source
myCSVFile.Close False


End Sub
```

Comment: first, you will probably need to change this `"C:\UsersDesktop\Repository\myExcel.xlsx"` to this `"C:\Users\Desktop\Repository\myExcel.xlsx"`

Comment: and then change all of these: `Workbooks("myExcel.xlsx")` to this `myExcel`

Comment: and these `Workbooks("wantedFile.xlsx")` to this `wantedFile`

Comment: thank you I have done what you have said I know I have updated my question

Comment: Did you see my other 2 comments? It does not look like you made those changes.

Comment: I have deleted .xlsx but I forget to update the code

Comment: What is the green/yellow highlight? Is that how your original CSV file looks? Please edit your post with such contents not as a screenshot but as text. How? Simply, open csv in text editor (not Excel) then copy+paste few top rows here and then format it with `{}` button in SO's edit toolbar. This makes for a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and many will gladly help you!

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

`Workbooks("myExcel").Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A:B").Copy Workbooks("wantedFile").Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A:B")`

need to look more like this:

`myExcel.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A:B").Copy wantedFile.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A:B")`

Comment: The same thing happend the wantedFilexls  contain all data not formatted